# Conditional Get

Tags: c#, json, http, caching

I want to connect to an API through C# which delivers json response but only to download the last modified json from the url.So I dont want to make unnecessary Get requests and want to check the headers for Last-Modified,eTag or Content-Length and check if the json response was modified then make a Get request and download only the last updated part of the Json.

Here are the response headers I get from a request:

`Cache-Control:"no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
Content-Encoding:"gzip"
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
Date:"Sun, 11 Jan 2015 18:47:55 GMT"
Expires:"Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
Pragma:"no-cache"
Server:"nginx"
X-Firefox-Spdy:"3.1"`

And here are the request headers:

`User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8"
Accept-Language:"en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate"
Cookie:"sid=i7e9lrhkju078ek1trj58tq406"
Connection:"keep-alive"
Cache-Control:"max-age=0"`

I just didnt write here the Host parameter.

Looking at these headers is it possible to ask the server every second if the response document was updated and if updated download only the updated part of the document?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Get requests or HEAD requests would meet your first need. Take a look at sections 9.3 & 9.4 in [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) page and you will find details. Please do keep in mind that the server has to support these headers/requests for this to work (not just the web server but also the application itself it the response is dynamically created). As for downloading only the modified part of the document, it really depends on if/how the server implements it.

Comment: I sent If-Modified-Since with the request with numerous datetime values.(ex. If-Modified-Since: Mon, 12 Jan 2015 10:00:00 GMT) but whatever datetime value I send the response is always 200 OK.And the content is the same.The result is the same with If-Unmodified-Since.If-Match, If-None-Match and If-Range requires a key to be sent to the server.How can I generate a key to be sent with these headers?